# Searchview with ListView will not work

Tags: java, android, listview, android-search

I am working on a project that creates a list view of notes. I tried to implement a search view so I could allow the user to filter the created notes. I am having trouble figuring out what I am doing wrong. I have looked at every post I could find, and walk through every tutorial. I just cannot get it. Whenever I type anything into the search view, everything is filtered away. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    NoteAdaptor na;
    ArrayList<Note> notes;
    SearchView searchView;

    private ListView nListViewNotes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        nListViewNotes = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListViewNotes);

        notes = Utilities.getAllSavedNotes(this);

        na = new NoteAdaptor(this, R.layout.item_note, notes);
        nListViewNotes.setAdapter(na);

        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                na.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });        
    }

    @Override
    //adds the "+" to the menu
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_main_new_note:
                //start NoteActivity in NewNote mode
                Intent newNoteActivity = new Intent(this, NoteActivity.class);
                startActivity(newNoteActivity);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        nListViewNotes.setAdapter(null);

        notes = Utilities.getAllSavedNotes(this);

        if(notes == null || notes.size() ==0){
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have no notes saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }else{

             na = new NoteAdaptor(this, R.layout.item_note, notes);
             nListViewNotes.setAdapter(na);

            //gets the file based what posistion the user clicked on
            nListViewNotes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String fileName = ((Note) nListViewNotes.getItemAtPosition(position)).getnDateTime()
                            + Utilities.FILE_EXTENSION;

                    Intent viewNoteIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteActivity.class);
                    viewNoteIntent.putExtra("NOTE_FILE", fileName);
                    startActivity(viewNoteIntent);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

My note class

```
public class Note implements Serializable{
    private long nDateTime;
    private String nTitle;
    private String nContent;
    private ArrayList nMentions;
    private ArrayList nTopics;
    private ArrayList nIDs;
    private ArrayList nRefs;

    public Note(long DateTime, String Title, String Content, ArrayList<String> Mentions, ArrayList<String> Topics, ArrayList<String> IDs
            ,ArrayList<String> Refs) {
        nDateTime = DateTime;
        nTitle = Title;
        nContent = Content;
        nMentions = Mentions;
        nTopics = Topics;
        nIDs = IDs;
        nRefs = Refs;
    }

    public long getnDateTime() {
        return nDateTime;
    }

    public String getnTitle() {
        return nTitle;
    }

    public String getnContent() {
        return nContent;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getnMentions() { return nMentions; }

    public ArrayList<String> getnTopics() { return nTopics; }

    public ArrayList<String> getnIDs() { return nIDs; }

    public ArrayList<String> getnRefs() { return nRefs; }

    public void setnDateTime(long nDateTime) {
        this.nDateTime = nDateTime;
    }

    public void setnTitle(String nTitle) {
        this.nTitle = nTitle;
    }

    public void setnContent(String nContent) {
        this.nContent = nContent;
    }

    public void setnMentions(ArrayList<String> nMentions) { this.nMentions = nMentions; }

    public void setnTopics(ArrayList<String> nTopics) { this.nTopics = nTopics; }

    public String getDateTimeAsString(Context context){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", context.getResources().getConfiguration().locale);
        sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

        return sdf.format(new Date(nDateTime));
    }
}
```

Note Adapter class

```
public class NoteAdaptor extends ArrayAdapter<Note> implements Filterable{

    private ArrayList notes = null;
    private ArrayList<Note> arraylist;
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;


    public NoteAdaptor(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Note> notes) {
        super(context, resource, notes);
        mContext = context;
        this.notes = notes;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(notes);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_note, null);
        }

        Note note = getItem(position);

        if (note!= null){
            TextView title =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_note_title);
            TextView date =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_note_date);
            TextView content =  (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_note_content);

            title.setText(note.getnTitle());
            date.setText(note.getDateTimeAsString(getContext()));            

            //in case the note is very long, we only preview a substring of that note
            if (note.getnContent().length() > 50){
                content.setText(note.getnContent().substring(0, 50));
            }else{
                content.setText(note.getnContent());
            }         
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        notes.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            notes.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (Note note : arraylist) {
                if (note.getnContent().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText) ||
                        note.getnTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                    notes.add(note);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Main xml

```
tools:context="com.brendan.notetakinghw2.MainActivity">

<SearchView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/searchView" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/mainListViewNotes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchView" />
```

Activity_Note xml

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.brendan.notetakinghw2.NoteActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/noteTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Title:"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:singleLine="true" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/noteContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="Enter your note here"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/noteTitle"
    android:layout_above="@+id/mentions" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mentions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_above="@+id/topics"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/topics"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_above="@+id/identifiers"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/identifiers"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_above="@+id/refrences"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/refrences"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Item_note xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_note_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    tools:text="TITLE" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_note_date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    tools:text="11/11/1111" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_note_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    tools:text="CONTENT" />

<!--<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_note_mentions"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    tools:text="MENTIONS" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_note_topics"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    tools:text="TOPICS"/>-->
```

Comment: What happens when you change the `if (note.getnContent().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText) ||
                        note.getnTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText))` criteria -- make more simple like adding every other `note`?

Comment: Try replace: na.getFilter().filter(newText); with na.filter(newText); Hope that help!